# JQuery - Disable single clickable column

Tags: jquery

I have a table that contains hidden rows that can be shown when the table row is clicked. This works great however one of the columns (colum 4) contains a link which when clicked I want to do something else and not show the hidden row. 
How can I make `column 4` not clickable except for the link?
I've made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/t7hezkhb/2/)

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table" width="100%;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>

        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="accordion">
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="myButton">Play</a></td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden-row">
        <td colspan="12">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <h4> More data hidden here</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    var $table = $('.table');
    $table.find('.hidden-row').hide();

    $table.find('.accordion').click(function() {
      $table.find('.accordion').not(this).nextAll('.hidden-row:first').fadeOut(500);
      $(this).nextAll('.hidden-row:first').slideToggle("slow");

    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the other answers do a fine job of answering the specific question of "Disable column click on clickable row", the actual *requirement* is to not "click" the row when the link is clicked.

> a link which when clicked I want to do something else and not show the hidden row

You can do this at the link level rather than the column level with a simple:

```
return false;
```

`return false` from jquery events calls event.stopPropagation which stops the click handler from "bubbling" up (via the td) to the tr.  This also stops the default action of the link (in this case navigating to `href='#'`).

---

In the case for this question, add this code:

```
$table.find(".accordion a").click(function(e) {
    // do something here
    $(this).text($(this).text() == "Play" ? "Pause" : "Play")
    // stop the row getting a click event
    e.stopPropagation();
    // also stop the row getting the click event (so don't need the above, it's for completeness)
    return false;
})
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t7hezkhb/3/

Comment: This is great and does what I want. If I have two elements with the same id /or different that are clickable within the row how can I make them both work. The code seems to only allow one element to work...hope I'm clear. Basically I now have two buttons that I want to work on the clickable row. Thanks.

Comment: just `return false` from the event handler for each of the buttons/link-buttons

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm afraid I'm not qute sure how to do this. Any chance of a clue?

Comment: Event handler = "onclick" function, eg `$("#mybutton").click(function() { ... do stuff ... ; return false; });`   how are you getting your buttons/links to "do" anything at the moment?  Wherever that is, add a return false.

Comment: Pretty much, just be careful to match the id names (disable2/disabled2) https://jsfiddle.net/drkjsLoj/3/

Comment: That's great, really good but one last question. Whilst the alerts work the href links to yahoo or google don't. I can;t figure that out...[link]https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/drkjsLoj/5/

Comment: If you're just going to redirect on a link, then who cares if it expands the row?  Just don't add a handler: https://jsfiddle.net/drkjsLoj/6/  (or, in the handler:  `location.href = $(this).attr("href");` )

Comment: Great, I see. Many thanks for all your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `non-clickable` class to the last column and check if the target element has `non-clickable` or `myButton` class. If it has then use `return false;` like,

```
if ($(e.target).hasClass('myButton') || $(e.target).hasClass('non-clickable')) {
   return false;
}
```

**Snippet,**

```js
$(function() {
  var $table = $('.table');
  $table.find('.hidden-row').hide();

  $table.find('.accordion').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('myButton') || $(e.target).hasClass('non-clickable')) {
      return false;
    }
    $table.find('.accordion').not(this).nextAll('.hidden-row:first').fadeOut(500);
    $(this).nextAll('.hidden-row:first').slideToggle("slow");

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table" width="100%;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="accordion">
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td class="non-clickable"><a href="#" class="myButton">Play</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden-row">
        <td colspan="12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <h4> More data hidden here</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check using if current clicked target is the fourth `td` in the clicked `tr` row

like `!(e.target == $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)")[0])`

check below snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    var $table = $('.table');
    $table.find('.hidden-row').hide();

    $table.find('.accordion').click(function(e) {
       
       if(!(e.target == $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)")[0])) { 
        
        $table.find('.accordion').not(this).nextAll('.hidden-row:first').fadeOut(500);
        
        $(this).nextAll('.hidden-row:first').slideToggle("slow");
        
       }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table" width="100%;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>

        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="accordion">
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="myButton">Play</a></td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden-row">
        <td colspan="12">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <h4> More data hidden here</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Which is great until you move the column / add another column and it all falls over.  Instead, add a class to the `td`s in that column and check for that (but otherwise the principle is sound).

Comment: changed for the fourth culmun as mentioned in question

Comment: Which is great until you move the column / add another column before it... etc  :)